# Android Studio doesn't read Samsung Galaxy S5

Tags: android

I installed all the latest SDK tools Android SDK Tools 24.3.3 and Android SDK Platform-tools 22,and unfortunaly android studio doesn't like my Samsung S5 Galaxy. It reads it as offline. You can see the picture.

[image: Android Studio Screen Shot.]

I tried the adb commands kill-server and start-server but with no result. I also turned off and on the USB Debugging from the Developer Options..

This is my gradle file code just in case I did something wrong there. I have another device connected to my mac which is recongised and is online.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.victory.walking.thewalkingviktory"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    '
 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.15'
compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

}
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: does your computer recognises your device, i.e. see your device manager

Comment: If your device is listed under other devices then problem with ur driver

Comment: which OS you are using?????

Comment: I am using the OS X Yosemite,Version 10.10.2.

Comment: Sorry, I have not used this OS, but I am sure that this problem is due to

Comment: driver of your device so please update driver of your phone

Comment: gradle has nothing to do with this, I was also having the same problem

Comment: on windows, that was resolved by updating driver

Comment: Alright. So how to update the driver of my phone? It is failry new so I didn't do much with it. I have also installed Kies.

Comment: update google usb driver on your system(computer)

Comment: or you can download a separate driver from internet for your phone on your system

Comment: I am inside the SDK manager right now,and unfortunately the Google USB Driver is not available for MAC OS:9(. So the only option is to download a separate driver from the net.

Comment: @Adi Tiwari, why are you spamming like 4 comments right after each other? You know comments can have multiple lines of text and can be edited afterwards. Maybe you think be press [Add Comment]. This very annoying to read.

Comment: I am new here and i didn't knew that @martijnn2008, because of some problem here i was not able to type more than few words in a comment thats why i did this.

Comment: Ok it is fixed. I had to do that factory reset thing. There was no other option for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just Switch Off your Phone, wait for few seconds and then again switch ON and then connect.

Answer (score 0):

Install Samsung Kies then see if it is detecting or not.

See if debugging option is on or not in your phone.